# Document event does not bind to footer

Tags: javascript, safari, dom-events, footer

I just figured something weird out with Safari. When binding an "click" event onto "document" it seems that the footer won't be recognized as part of the document so it is not triggering the "click" event for the document.

Check example-code https://jsfiddle.net/falke88/v2ycdyhj/4/

```
$(document).on("click", function(){alert("hit!")});
//$('footer').on("click", function(){console.log("footer!")});
```

Open it with Safari Mobile (iPhone 6 etc.) and try to click inside the footer and outside (document area).

When clicking the footer nothing happens - when clicking outside the footers padding/dimensions it works.

Can anybody confirm this issue/feature?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine, except you cannot have the body as a sibling to another element.

You can do:

```
<someelement>
Testbody
</someelement>
<footer>
  Testfooter
</footer>
```

Or:

```
<body>
   <footer></footer>
</body>
```

See modified Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j9coh1eq/

Comment: Sorry I do not get your point. Surely footer will work if seperated as event selector. But footer won't trigger an event which is bound to document. In Android i.e. you can click the footer and it will trigger the event which is bound to document. But in Safari you click the footer and nothing happens

Comment: I might misunderstand something, but if you're clicking the footer element, you're not clicking the document - which essentially is an element underneath the footer.

Comment: Yea thats what happening only in safari. Using Chrome i.e. on mobile device or desktop you can click the footer and it will trigger the document event just like it is a part of the document. Just try the jsFiddle with android

Comment: Huh, that's odd. Didn't realize that. I don't have Safari readily available right now, so I can't test it. :/

Comment: Would be great if you can confirm that sooner or later - need to documentate that issue